# NAS without internet connection, but still get notifications

Tags: backup, vlan

I don't want our back-up Synology NAS to have a connection to the internet, but I still want to receive some kind of notification when there's something wrong with the hardware (the notification it can provide built-in).

Say that I connect the back-up NAS directly to the server, how could I still get notifications in some way when it has support for email messages or can report to a syslog server.

I was thinking of instead of directly attaching the back-up NAS to the server, to attach it to the switch in a separate VLAN for the back-up traffic, and give it at the same time access to the mail server or syslog server (that would still need to be created), if that would be possible.

Would that be a possible setup? Are there any possible issues to bear in mind?

Comment: It really depends entirely on what notification options the NAS gives you. Unfortunately you neither mentioned which NAS it is, nor what notification options it gives you. You may wish to add this information, so as to get better answers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You make a good point about the brand, so I added it. It's a Synology NAS. Thank you for your help

Comment: Usually, you define rules on your firewall that enable or disable Internet connections as desired.

Comment: @Zac67 It's not only about access to the internet, but also having the back-up NAS visible in the LAN. I prefer to have it secluded and give only access to it via the server, so security issues in the (maybe outdated) software cannot be abused by malware. Before we had one link to the server and one link to the LAN for management, but I changed that to a link aggr. directly to the server. The downside is: no management from multiple clients and no connection to the mail server for notifications. This mail traffic is only in the LAN, it doesn't necessarily require a connection to the internet.

Comment: @EarthMind If you want to protect your NAS you put it in a separate network/VLAN and filter accordingly on the router connecting the network. Alternatively, you configure restrictions on the NAS (if possible), either on the user or on the network level. If you isolate your NAS completely it can't communicate with the rest of the net. The only way would be across the server (routing, TCP forwarding, SMTP relay, ...).

Comment: Do you have an internal SMTP or Syslog server that the NAS can access? If so, then problem solved. Have it send notifications to the internal SMTP or Syslog server.

Comment: @joeqwerty Since it's connected directly to the server: no

Answer (score 2):

There are various basic approaches:

1. Switch it - connect it to the LAN switch and filter traffic by ACLs (which the switch would need to support)
2. Route it - put it in a VLAN of its own and configure the router to filter the traffic you want or don't want (router needs to be fast)
3. Secure it - using local user configuration or the local NAS firewall/network settings, restrict access as far as possible
4. Patch it - using either routing, TCP forwarding, or an SMTP relay on the server, enable the NAS to make the connections you need while everything else is kept separate

Best practice would be a combination of 1. and 2. - a layer 3 switch - plus 3.